# On $\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{gd}(x+y)}{\exp(x+y)}dx\right)dy$, being $\operatorname{gd}(u)$ the Gudermannian function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

While I was playing with Wolfram Alpha online calculator, to create double integrals involving negative exponentials and the so-called Gudermannian function, denoted in this post as $\operatorname{gd}(u)$, I wondered that should be possible to get the closed-form of $$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{gd}(x+y)}{e^{x+y}}dx\right)dy.\tag{1}$$
I believe that $(1)$ hasn't a very nice closed-form (I was trying to define integrals involving these functions with a nice closed-form).

> **Question.** Can you justify/calculate the closed-form of $(1)$? **Many thanks.**

Comment: Many thanks to the user who upvoted the post.

Comment: You could also accept my answer.

Comment: @Somos I am going to wait if there are more contributions, before accepting an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that is ok. I should have waited at least a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Wolfram Cloud Sandbox](https://snadbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

```
In[1] := Integrate[Integrate[Gudermannian[x+y]/Exp[x+y],{x,0,Infinity}],{y,0,1}]//Simplify//InputForm
Out[1]//InputForm= 1 - Pi^2/24 - Gudermannian[1]/E + Log[2/(1 + E^2)] - PolyLog[2, -E^2]/2
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.